# help needed recovering filesystem for backup

Tags: drivers, nautilus, display, data-recovery

Got myself in a bit of trouble on a previously smoothly running system. Here is the story so far: yesterday I switched to a propriatary ATI driver instead of the Nouveau driver that I ran uo to that time. The Ati driver ran fine but at next bootup there were problems. No sound (and appearantly no discovearable soundcards) and weird sizing of screens. So i learnt my lesson about dodgy prop drivers and wanted to go back to good old Noveau. in Settings UI, i selected the X.org Nouveau driver and rebooted. Now I got new errors but the system still managed to boot into graphical mode. However in the additional-drivers tab of system settings, it didnt displays the previously selected ATI driver, but a manually installed one (I do not remember exactly which). That was weird, but i wasnt that worried still. I decided to purge and reinstall X.org along with lightdm and plymouth. and afterwards reinstall ubuntu desktop, which I had done succesfully in the past. This time however, it failed. When I next booted this is what I got:

http://picpaste.com/20160228_152835-LUNf7Vwi.jpg

So my display drivers and server are pretty screwed up.

After getting this error, I booted into recovery mode to see what was up. I took a look at any broken packages in the recovery menu dpkg menu item. Strangely enough, this listed some -I believe 3- broken Nautilus packages. (I hit 'd' for details to discover this. I didnt do 'y' to repair), and exited.

So now seemed a good time to at least back up my files before trying anything else..

But after another reboot to recovery-mode and dropping into a shell prompt, I did a cd /home and then ls -l. That gives me 0 files and directories. /home/myhomedir doesnt show anymore. However, If I run the live cd, I can still see my volume with all files intact. I have also mounted an external drive in my live-cd environment. But copying the files from local drive to external drive doesnt work. I get "permission denied" for most files. gksudo(or gksu) nautilus doesnt work. It says program gksu is not installed. So recovering user files with a Live CD is turning out to be tricky. So:

1)I would like help backing up the /home dirs on my local disk to an external drive. either by using the live cd or from terminal shell. I assume i somehow need to force a read/write mount of the volume, but i do not know how. 2)Having done that I'd appreciate any pointers on restoring X.org and nouveau drivers and getting filesystem back to working order without doing a full reinstall. (I realise I might need to split the question up in two separate AU questions. please advise)

btw: I do not have an encrypted home drive. My system is a dell inspiron i5 running 15.10 64bit ubuntu desktop.

Any help appreciated!

Mat

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to backup my home directory quite easily. I didnt realize I was still able to log in to my user account by simply ctrl alt f1. I could then mount an external drive and save everything I needed to keep.

The second point however proved far more difficult and I ended up giving up and deciding on a full reinstall.

I tried several 2 different approaches:

1. fully blocking anything connected to non-XORG/Nouveau, so basically  uninstalling (and even blacklisting fglrx) and fully reinstalling
   XORG several times
2. trying to get the AMD/Radeon card to work on either the open-source drivers or the prop ones, using mainly this guide:
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Well both objectives failed. I discovered that the Radeon has many issues in Linux. Mainly this one looks very much like my issue:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88364

Though not fully solved, I hope it will be of use to anyone still.